# No syntax coloring in vim for me, but ok for my students

Tags: vim, colors

My students get syntax coloring in vim, but I don't!

Even when I "syntax on" as a command `syntax on` or put it in my `.vimrc` and/or `.exrc`.

The terminal is xterm.

I am missing something in vim or is there something in my .profile -- it has been growing for 30 years...  And I've been hacking at this problem for a year.

Thanks for listening

Comment: Are you all using the same machine? Do you get syntax coloring if you run `\vim -u /dev/null` and run `:syntax on`? Are the tildes blue, by the way? Do you get colors in the same terminal with other programs, e.g. `ls --color`?

Comment: Also, what does `tput colors` (from the shell) print?  What about `:echo has("syntax")` inside vim?

Comment: I do get colors in ls and colored tilders and numbers in vi/vim.@ Gilles.  I ran tput colors and got the output 8.....  And now I have colors in vim! WTF!

Comment: OK.  Got it.  Two versions of "vi". /bin/vi and /usr/bin/vim.And I'm old enough to type 'vi' rather than 'vim'.

Comment: I added `alias vi='vim'` so I *can't* type vi.  Not without overriding the alias.  I'd only typed 'vi' once or twice before adding the alias to my .bashrc, but it sure is jarring to not see my familar colors and setup.

Comment: What's your distribution; and what type of file is being edited?

Comment: Is the `vi` in `/bin` the old vi or is it just the vim-minimalistic? I had that problem too after a system upgrade some days ago.

Answer (score 8):

This issue was driving me nuts (again) today, everything suggested here almost work, but actual colors never appeared. 'syntax on' enabled bold underlined and everything except actual colors. As i suspected the problem was related to my terminal/env and the simple solution was:

```
export TERM=xterm-color
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's the only think that works for me. Thanx a 1,000,000

Answer (score 6):

The right command is this one :

```
:syntax enable
```

Comment: `:syntax on` has worked perfectly well on every machine I've used. Do you have a citation for `enable` being better?

Comment: And I always used enable, just learned the existence of "on" here ! In fact after typing `:help syntax-on` I saw it worked. just do `:help syntax-enable` to see it's ok too. The differences I see (after test) is that "enable" allow to use different syntax highlighter as the automatic detection made with the file extension, while "syntax on" didn't.

To test : open vim for a file called "sample", and one other "sample.txt", you will see the difference

Comment: I saw that, `on` is the same unless you have some particular customization. That's not the problem here (he actually solved the problem, see the last comment on the question).

Comment: `:sy on` is shorter

Answer (score 1):

Check the output for `dpkg -l | grep vim`. Either `vim-gtk` for Kubuntu or `vim-gnome`  should be in the list, otherwise you're probably working with `vim-tiny` which doesn't support syntax highlighting.

To solve it:

- On Kubuntu: `apt-get install vim-gtk`
- On Ubuntu `apt-get install vim-gnome`

Comment: If you work only with `vim` and not with `gvim`, installing `vim-nox` would be enough. However, if you want to [access the X clipboard in `vim`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard), you need to install either `vim-gtk` or `vim-gnome`.